how to make more diversity generation with Wave function collapse
I am working on a procedural generation project using the Wave Function Collapse algorithm in Python with Pygame. While the current implementation generates patterns, I am looking to enhance the diversity and complexity of the generated output. I would appreciate insights on how to improve the algorithm to achieve this goal.
import pygame
import sys
import random

def sprite_sheet_cutter(path,width,height,size):
    imgs = []
    sprite_sheet = pygame.transform.scale_by(pygame.image.load(path),size)
    sheet_width,sheet_height = sprite_sheet.get_size()
    for x in range(0,sheet_width,width):
        imgs.append(sprite_sheet.subsurface((x,0,width,height)))
    return tuple(imgs)

Neighbor_Cell = ((-1,0),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,0))

def Rule_exceuss(list1,Rule):
    return_list = []
    for i in list1:
        if i in Rule:
            return_list.append(i)
    return return_list


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((832, 672))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

        Title1 = sprite_sheet_cutter("Image/Grass.png",16,16,1)
        Title2 = sprite_sheet_cutter("Image/Shore.png",16,16,1)

        self.assets = {
        "High_Grass":(Title1[2],("High_Grass","Low_Grass")),
        "Low_Grass":(Title1[1],("Low_Grass","High_Grass","Sand")),
        "Sand":(Title2[0],("Low_Grass","Sand","Shore_Water")),
        "Shore_Water":(Title2[1],("Sand","Shore_Water","Sea_Water")),
        "Sea_Water":(Title2[2],("Sea_Water,Shore_Water,Low_Water")),
        "Low_Water":(Title2[3],("Sea_Water","Low_Water","Deep_Water")),
        "Deep_Water":(Title2[4],("Low_Water","Deep_Water")),
        }

        self.Cellist = {}
        self.Node_list = {(800,16):WFC_Node((800,16),self,["High_Grass"])
        }

    def Run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.screen.fill((255,255,255))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

            try:
                self.WFC(min(self.Node_list.values(),key=lambda x: len(x.option)))
            except:
                print("Done")

            for Cell in self.Cellist.values():
                Cell.Render(self.screen)

            
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)

        pygame.mixer.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


    def WFC(self,cell):
        if len(cell.option) > 1:
            print(cell.option)
            cell.option = [random.choice(cell.option)]
        self.Cellist[cell.pos] = cell.Create_Cell()

        for i in Neighbor_Cell:
            pos = (cell.pos[0] +i[0]*16,cell.pos[1] +i[1]*16)
            if 0 <= pos[0] < 832 and 0 <= pos[1] < 672 and pos not in self.Cellist:
                if pos not in self.Node_list.keys():
                    self.Node_list[pos] = WFC_Node(pos,self)
                    self.Node_list[pos].option = Rule_exceuss(self.Node_list[pos].option,self.assets[cell.option[0]][1])
                elif len(self.Node_list[pos].option) > 1:
                    self.Node_list[pos].option = Rule_exceuss(self.Node_list[pos].option,self.assets[cell.option[0]][1])

        self.Node_list.pop(cell.pos)


class WFC_Node:
    def __init__(self,pos,game,option = ["High_Grass","Low_Grass","Sand","Shore_Water","Sea_Water","Low_Water","Deep_Water"]):
        self.option = option
        self.game = game
        self.pos = pos

    def Create_Cell(self):
        return Cell(self.pos,self.game.assets[self.option[0]][0])


class Cell:
    def __init__(self,pos,sprite):
        self.pos = pos
        self.sprite = sprite

    def Render(self,surf):
        surf.blit(self.sprite,self.pos)

Game().Run()

I have implemented a basic WFC algorithm that generates patterns based on a set of predefined rules and options. However, the generated patterns lack the desired diversity and not optimized
